# Scala passing method to supers constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, functional-programming

I'd like to have a hierarchy where the base class can take a function in its constructor and a derived class can supply a method as that function. There is one way to do it below but it's ugly. I have to declare the child's function in the constructor arg list of the super's constructor. That means the function is anonymous and so not a method of the Child class (though I don't think I care about that). The real code will be long and this will end up difficult to read, especially if I had more than one of these functions.

Thus:

```
class A[T](s1: String, s2: String, w: (String, String) => Unit){
  def go: Unit = {
    w(s1, s2)
  }
}

val externalWriter = { (s1: String, s2: String) =>
    println (s1+s2)
}

val w1 = new A[String]("Hello ", "world", externalWriter)
w1.go

case class B(s1: String, s2: String) extends A[String](s1, s2, w = { (a: String, b: String) =>
    println ("Class B:"+a+b)
  }){
  def write: Unit = go
}

val w2 = B("Hey  ","guys")
w2.write
```

w1.go prints "Hello world" and w2.write prints "Class B: Hey guys". So this does what I want but is there a way to have `w` be a method or val of class B and still pass it into the super's constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something somewhat similar to monkjack's solution, but using more of a mixin pattern. The key difference here being that I'm using an anonymous refinement of `A` to create `w1`, allowing me to keep `w` as a method.

```
abstract class A(s1: String, s2: String) {
  def w(arg1: String, arg2: String): Unit
  def go(): Unit = {
    w(s1, s2)
  }
}

val w1 = new A("Hello", "World") {
  def w(a: String, b: String): Unit = println(a + b)
}
w1.go()

case class B(s1: String, s2: String) extends A(s1, s2) {
  def w(a: String, b: String): Unit = println("Class B:" + a + b)
  def write: Unit = go
}

val w2 = B("Hey  ", "guys")
w2.write

trait C {
  def w(a: String, b: String): Unit = println("Trait C:" + a + b)
}

val w3 = new A("Bye ", "everyone") with C
w3.go()
```

Comment: I had no idea you could define w in the body of a new, very interesting. The downside is you have to know that to use it. @monkjack would make the option explicit. Also this would be rather verbose if it had a long ```w```definition since it would go inline in the scope where it is used. Hmmm...

Comment: Clever though useful in a bunch of cases.

Comment: You could just as well define `w` in another trait, and mix that trait in when you instantiate, if you don't want to do it inline. I'll add another example

Comment: OK, now you have it. I've been struggling with how to do this with traits. Now you just define a new trait for arbitrary writers and mixin with a simple ```with N``` at instantiation. You've taught me a couple really useful things, I hope someone else finds this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, have the function you are passing in as a abstract member, and then implement it in your case classes, and offer a pre-canned implementation that accepts it via the constructor:

```
  abstract class A(s1: String, s2: String) {
    def w: (String, String) => Unit
    def go(): Unit = {
      w(s1, s2)
    }
  }

  class InlineA(s1: String, s2: String, w1: (String, String) => Unit) extends A(s1, s2) {
    def w = w1
  }

  val externalWriter = { (s1: String, s2: String) =>
    println(s1 + s2)
  }

  val w1 = new InlineA("Hello ", "world", externalWriter)
  w1.go()

  case class B(s1: String, s2: String) extends A(s1, s2) {
    def w = { (a: String, b: String) =>
      println("Class B:" + a + b)
    }
    def write(): Unit = go()
  }

  val w2 = B("Hey  ", "guys")
  w2.go()
```